# MVC opens controller from another branch

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, model-view-controller

This is odd.

I have two working branches in my MVC project. One branch is the 'team' branch and another is 'my' branch.

I am trying to merge some of 'my' files to the 'team' branch so i can push them to the test site.

However, when i added the files (a few views, one model, and updated an already existing controller), ran the project, navigated to the desired page i realized that it was using the controller on 'my' branch and not the 'team' branch.

I have confirmed that i am using the 'team' model but i am using 'my' controller and 'my' view.

Any help?

Comment: How did you know it was using the other branch? Did you see the file path to the other branch in an exception message? Are you using a web site (File->New Web Site) or a web application project (File->New Project, with a vbproj file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why.

but i fixed it by just simply closing my project and re-opening it.

I tried several times to do 'cleaning' and 'rebuilding' of the solution but it never fixed it.

Comment: Sometimes that's all it takes :)